# What is this soldering tweezer like tool called?

Tags: pcb, soldering, tools

I long ago used a tool in a workshop which looks very like a metal tweezer but unlike a tweezer its holder arms are normally tightly closed and opens when one pushes it. So it was used to hold lets say a resistor to be attached to PCB holes firmly when soldering.

I need that tool but I hope I could describe it clear but my search failed in web so far.

Comment: you described a `clamp` .... combine that with `tweezer` in your search

Comment: It is not this one: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Ha535cee4cbb641a3a0fe90b9b6b1ee443/Third-Hand-Soldering-Iron-Stand-Clamp-Helping-Hands-Clip-Tool-PCB-Holder-Electrical-Circuits-Hobby.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp  It was like a tweezer.

Comment: I think I found it https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbeKVJY_E1mGZRKvAp4MtArwad4SJ0450cJA&usqp=CAU

Comment: A similar tool that may prove useful is a hemostat: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemostat

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are called [**cross-locking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweezers) or **reverse-action** tweezers.

[image: Cross-Locking Tweezer Example]
<sup>Lucasbosch, CC BY-SA 3.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0, via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Comment: As a side note, these are extremely useful for soldering small SMD components, though if you end up with a pair with too strong or a grip, be prepared for them to turn into tiny projectile launchers. Always order spare components!

Comment: Personally, I like to use protective glasses/goggles with them... catching a flying SMD component in the eye isn't exactly fun... plus it's a convenient way to add a little visual magnification.

Comment: Personally, I hate these, far less controllable than a standard pair of tweeers

Comment: They're also called heat-shuts, when used to help stop (de)soldering heat travelling to the component body

Comment: For small SMD work, say 0402 or 0603, you typically want to hold the component with the tweezers first, solder one side briefly to position it, then move the tweezer to press down the component instead, solder the other side proper, go back to the first side and sold it proper too. This prevents "tombstoning" due to capillary action, where one pad could otherwise end up slightly in the air. I think reverse action tweezers would be hard to use for that? But then I've never really worked with them either.